# Add /usr/local/lib to g++ library search path permanently

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I want to make g++ linker(ld) search for libraries starting in the directory `/usr/local/lib`. How do I permanently add `/usr/local/lib` to the search path for the linker?

The problem is that I am trying to link the library *libboost_program_options.a* to my source. There are two copies of the library, one in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and the other in `/usr/local/lib`. How do I make the linker first look in `/usr/local/lib` and pick that instead of the other one?

The output of `ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'` on my system:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl:
/usr/lib/nvidia-304:
/usr/lib32/nvidia-304:
/lib32:
/usr/lib32:
/lib:
/usr/lib:
/usr/lib/nvidia-304/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
/usr/lib32/nvidia-304/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
```

The output of `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012`

```
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67781/use-shared-libraries-in-usr-local-lib

Comment: @SimonKraemer I want the change to be permanent, and there is already a libc.conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d containing the required line. I want to alter the search order. ld should start looking from /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 1):

The search path is specified in the linker scripts used during compilation. Run `gcc -v foo.c` to perform a link and see which linker script is used. In my case, it is `/usr/lib/ldscripts/elf_x86_64.x`. In that linker script, you will find `SEARCH_DIR` directives. Update it to include `/usr/local/lib`.

Note that `ldconfig` and `ld.so.conf.d` are only used at runtime.